# Add a simple target line parallel to x-axis, in Nivo @nivo/ResponsiveLine

Tags: reactjs, charts, nivo-react

Trying to get this grey line parallel to x-axis as a marker of target (at of y-axis 67%).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may put a markers props like:

```
markers={[
    {
        axis: 'y',
        value: 520,
        legend: 'TEST',
        lineStyle: {
            stroke: 'red',
        },
        textStyle: {
            fill: 'red',
        },
    },
]}
```

the value determine the marker location, you can calculate based on data you passed.

Comment: This workes for me.
Sorry for super later acknowledgement, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: What happens when there is no 520 yet? Is there a way for the graph to show the y axis up to 520?